# Syncing Apple Music between iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, apple-music

How do you sync playlists, favorites, etc between devices in the new Apple Music app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is turn on "iCloud Music Library" and all of your playlists, saved songs etc. will be distributed to all of your devices (including PC, Mac, iPhone, iPod and iPad (and soon to be android and Apple TV))

To do this, on iDevices go to Settings>Music>iCloud Music Library.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot that the button in settings had become unchecked when I signed out and back into Apple Music. It's very confusing!